# Spawning multiple celery tasks dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing, io, celery

I have a celery tasks that generates a list of items, specifically a list of slices from an image, and I want to be able to start a task to process each of the generated slices. Assume I have something similar to this:

```py
@app.task()
def slice(img_path, width, height):
    result = []
    img = Image.open(img)
    for box in get_slice_boxes(width, height):
        result.append(img.crop(box))
    return result

@app.task()
def process(img_slice):
   # do something with the image slice
```

I've tried using a chord with a `.map` but as far as I understand I would need to have the list of items at the moment of the task instantiation which would require to run the `slice` task in the foreground. What I'm aiming for is to slice the image in the background and start one `process` task for each.
Is this even possible to do with celery? Is there a way I can achieve a similar result with something besides celery?